# Angular 2 stops working on page refresh

Tags: angular

got a bit silly question, but can't work it out by myself.

I've got an Angular 2 application with authorization, API calls, and stuff.

When you load some content, let's say mysite.com/users for the first time - everything works fine. I get the api response and render the page.

But when you just refresh the page - you get again the api response and the javascript works as expected, but the UI is not rendering any dynamic content (ngIf, ngFor, whatever).

The only way to make it work again - get back to home page and then move to the old page again.

Could you please let me know any advice or guide where to look for to aim this issue?

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to learn how to ask a good question! This question is vague and contains no specific code questions.

Comment: I occasionally run into problems where refreshing a route will not load the data correctly for the route I am currently on. If this is the case, you will need to work thorough altering your ngOnInit and route guards to ensure your data is loaded correctly. Do you have any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in app.module in providers

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

...
providers: [
{
  provide: LocationStrategy,
  useClass: HashLocationStrategy
},
...],
...
```